# output of `svn status -uq` has no newlines in script

Tags: bash, ssh, svn

```
function runstatus {
    echo "SVN Status -uq:"
    echo 
    status=$(svn status -uq)
    echo $status
    echo $bigline
}
```

This prints something like:

> SVN Status -uq:
>
> rd_backup rd_backup.sh update 764 update Status against revision: 771

Whereas normally, manually running the command instead of `./update`, it looks like:

> svn status -uq
>
> M       *      764   update
>
> Status against revision:    771

ie with newlines. How can I make sure the formatting stays the same, and is legible, when running from a script?

Comment: Why not just run `svn status -uq` instead of `echo`ing the output of `$(svn status -uq)`?

Comment: Oh yeah that does seem to make a lot more sense actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a function to just show the output of a command, there's no need to capture the output and then `echo`  it again.

Just run `svn status -uq` directly. The stdout will be output from the function call as well.

---

If you really need to use variables and `echo` them, you need to quote the argument passed to `echo` if you want the whitespace to be preserved: `echo "$status"`.

The reason is that `$status` will literally contain the following:

```
M * 764 update
Status against revision: 771
```

When you run `echo $status`, `echo` will be called like this:

```
echo M * 764 update \
Status against revision: 771
```

This is more than one parameter, since Bash splits arguments on whitespace ([see `$IFS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)). `echo` will print each argument, separated by one space, so while the rest of the line looks fine, the newline will – in essence – be collapsed to one space.

If you surround the argument with a quote, `echo` will only see it as one argument and correctly output it again.

The Bash Wiki has [a good read on quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and lists a few reasons why you should *always* quote your variables apart from a few exceptions.

Comment: See "Word Splitting" in the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting